# Mass energy equivalence of photons

Tags: photons, mass, protons

It is said  that elementary particles get their mass from the Higgs field. Also 99% of the mass of a proton comes from the strong force binding its quarks together. So we say that the mass energy equivalence of the strong force gives 99% of a protons mass. Even if the Higgs field disappeared a proton would still have  mass from this equivalence.

My question is why can we say a proton has the mass due to the energy in it's binding of the quarks, but a photon is said to have no mass but has energy. In this case we don't  use the energy mass equivalence to say a photon has mass, as we do with a proton

Comment: 0 mass elementary particles stll obey the mathematics of special relativity http://hyperphysics.phy-astr.gsu.edu/hbase/Relativ/relcon.html#relcon

Answer (score 0):

Mass is just the energy in the rest frame. A photon has no rest frame and in the limit towards it tends to have zero energy - due to redshift. A proton on the other hand does have a rest frame and has 938 MeV rest energy.

Comment: It is said that if the Higgs field disappeared a Proton would still possess mass from the strong force. But in this situation it's component quarks would have no mass. But we still use this mass energy equivalence to say the proton has mass. The quarks here would have no rest mass just like the proton.

Comment: @RiellyDiefenbach you are forgetting the gluons as part of the protons make-up here, they are also massless but self interact and are bound, just like the quarks in the proton. A single massless particle might not have a rest frame, but a system of massless particles can.

Comment: Sure this seems to be what's observed  or thought. However it isn't an explanation of why. Why can a system of massless particles, which by definition are moving at the speed of light somehow possess a rest mass based on the energy of the system, but a single particle doesn't

Comment: A system of photons can have a rest mass, e.g. in positronium decay to 2 gammas, the energy is $2m_e$, but the momentum is zero (in the positronium COM frame).

Answer (score 0):

When you say that mass and energy are *equivalent*, you are referring to Einstein's famous equation $E=mc^2$. Adding energy in any form (kinetic energy, binding energy, etc.) to a particle increases its *mass* - changing both its inertia and gravitational force (both proportional to the mass).

However, when you said that "the photon has no mass" you used the word "mass" differently - this time you are referring to **rest** mass. A proton has non-zero rest mass because if brought to rest (i.e., zero momentum or zero kinetic energy), it  still has this non-zero energy (or equivalently, mass). A photon cannot be slowed down from the speed of light, and in particular it can't be brought to rest in any frame of reference. As such it must have zero rest mass - none of its energy can be said to be available at rest, because it can't be at rest.

Comment: The only mass concept nowadays is that of rest mass.